# How to redirect to a page after login while send a token as a hander to middleware both using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm using nextJS, express JS and JWT for my application. I've setup 2 pages login and admin where admin page is made protected that is only accessible after verifying token by JWT. I'm willing to redirect to admin page immediately after successful login.

The token is generated after successful login and stored in the local storage whereas the admin page is made protected using a middleware that verifies the token.

Here I'm facing 2 issues:

1) How can I redirect immediately after successful login attempt?

2) How can I send the token that is stored in localstorage as a header to middleware function?

Please have a look at my code below

```
// SUBMIT BUTTON CLICK
checkCredential = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();

 const respsonse = await axios.post("/api/admin/login", this.state);
 const { token } = respsonse.data;
 localStorage.setItem("auth-token", token);

};

// THIS END POINT HIT FOR LOGIN CHECKS

login: async (req, res) => {
 const adminExist = await Admin.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
 if (!adminExist) return res.status(400).send("Email doest exists");

 const validPass = req.body.password === adminExist.password;
 if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Incorrect Password");

 const token = jwt.sign({ id: adminExist._id }, "KEY_HERE");
 res.set("auth-token", token);
 return res
  .json({ token })
  .redirect(301, "/admin"); //this is working but redirecting isn't reflecting on my screen
}

//  ADMIN PAGE IS PROTECTED BY MIDDLEWARE

 server.get("/admin", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res);
});

// MIDDLEWARE VERIFY TOKEN
  verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.header("auth-token");

if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access Denied");

try {
  const verified = jwt.verify(token, "HEY_HERE");
  req.user = verified;
  next();
} catch (err) {
  res.status(400).send("Invalid Token");
}
};
```

To be precise, I want to immediately redirect to admin page after successful login and that works by user attempt a successful login, token generate and stored in local storage. Immediately the token is passed to the middleware (verifyToken) as a header fetched from local storage and the route get redirect to admin page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, login (ExpressJS in backend) method checks for user credentials and that's it, all routing must be implemented from frontend. You do not redirect client from backend, but pass back to frontend JSON object with success or failure for the login.

```
login: async (req, res) => {
 //...
 return res
  .json({ token, success: true })
  //this is working but redirecting isn't reflecting on my screen
  //.redirect(301, "/admin");
}
```

Then in frontend (NextJS/ReactJS) you implement protection of your resources, by checking if JWT token is valid and user have permissions to access resources.

This is really good resource for implementing JWT backend+frontend: https://medium.com/@faizanv/authentication-for-your-react-and-express-application-w-json-web-tokens-923515826e0

Comment: Hi @Janiis. Thank for your views. The thing is I'm using nextJS which is server side rendering library. I have to redirect my route from backend as technically react is rendered from backend in nextJS. If I were using ReactJS with react-router-dom. it would have been much easier. 

anyway. Thanks

Comment: @NoorMuhammad thanks for your response, this depends on the structure of the app and the implementation. I have implemented JWT with NextJS (SSR) user access to resources in frontend with no problems using HOC for Auth and getInitialProps to get data from server with headers (JWT cookie).

Comment: Thanks . The issue is resolved now. The routing is done by next js router itself and the the header is set by res.set method present in express.